# How to display the number on which the compound number is divisible in the Inventor app

Tags: primes, app-inventor

I am making a simple app that give n and says is prime or is compound.
Now I want make it some better. For example when we import 25, it says 25 is compound because it is divisible by 5.
I made my app for student project with app inventor.
Please help me.
Thanks a Lot!

Ehsan Amiri

Comment: The correct mathematical description for a non-prime number is "composite".  25 is a composite number.  Almost right. :)

Comment: You are awesome rossum

Answer (score 0):

Your inputted number MUST BE BIGGER than 9, then the easiest way to do it is to divide the inputted number with all integers starting from 2 until 9 and check the remainder of the result.

[image: math's remainder block]

If the remainder for any of those integers (2 until 9) is ZERO then it is non-prime number, on the other hand, if the resulting remainder for all those integers are NOT ZERO then the inputted number is prime.